# SpadeR outputs in a loop

Tags: r

So I'm using the SpadeR package on R to test similarities of pairs of abundance data for my thesis. Does anyone have any idea of how to turn an output into a matrix for further analysis?

Here is the code im working with:

```
CompAB <- mydata %>% select(2, 3)
dataAB <- data.matrix(CompAB, rownames.force = NA)
SimilarityPair(dataAB, datatype = c("abundance"), nboot = 1000)
```

I want to do this so I can later loop the outputs from a randomisation run and put them into a matrix to analyse

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `matrix()` command?